# Increase video resolution in flutter youtube app using pod player package

Tags: android, flutter, dart, youtube

I am creating a YouTube application using flutter and I am trying to increase the video resolution to 1080 and use the pod player package, but the resolution does not appear except for 720

```
 youtubController!.changeVideo(
      playerConfig: const PodPlayerConfig(
        autoPlay: true,
        isLooping: false,
        videoQualityPriority: [1080, 720, 360, 144],
      ),
      playVideoFrom: PlayVideoFrom.youtube('https://youtu.be/$value'),
    );

 youtubController!.changeVideo(
      playerConfig: const PodPlayerConfig(
        autoPlay: true,
        isLooping: false,
        videoQualityPriority: [1080, 720, 360, 144],
      ),
      playVideoFrom: PlayVideoFrom.youtube('https://youtu.be/$value'),
    );
```